# Closing sudo password

Tags: command-line

I cant download not a thing on Ubuntu download center.I dont know my root password.
Its always wants sudo password.And I cant write it(ı dont even know it though)

How can ı close or inactive it?

Answer (score 1):

- If you have installed Ubuntu, you have typed a password when you created your username : it is that one called "sudo" password.
- If your Ubuntu was installed by another person, that person have set a password for you. Ask him about it.

Note : if you use a professionnal PC, in your workplace for example, it is perfectly normal that the IT team set a password to prevent workers from accessing important things on the computer. So your only option here would be to ask them direclty.

Comment: Okay ı got it.But ı have one more question.I cant write it.In terminal no button is working?

Comment: In terminal you will not see it but it is there. Just type it.

Comment: just type your password without viewing it then press enter.